# Allowing VPN Users To Specific URLs

Tags: vpn

I'd like to allow users that use my VPN server to access the URLs I specificed.

E.g. I set up the VPN server and users login and connect via my server. They can access any resource on internet through my VPN server. But then I want to limit the access to specific resources even defined with wildcard urls like *.mydomain.com.

Is this possible for any VPN server?

Edit: Currently i use a proxy server to provide access through my server's ip address. But the proxy server causes problems. So if users use vpn connection they can connect as in my network. İt's possible but i wonder if it can be filtered for some requests for some users.

Comment: do you want to allow only some certain internet resources?

Comment: Yes. Just i specified ones

Comment: you should handle this at proxy layer, why don't use something like http://dansguardian.org/ , so it would be easy to specify ok urls?

Comment: i don't need a filter. Currently i use a proxy server to provide access through my server's ip address. But the proxy server causes problems. So if users use vpn connection they can connect as in my network. İt's possible but i wonder if it can be filtered for some requests for some users.